# Is there any way to generate a random real matrix with all complex eigenvalues in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, complexity-theory, eigenvalue

How can we randomly create a real squared matrix A and all of its eigenvalues are complex number λ=a+bi in Matlab?

Comment: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W11b.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'll first take a random n X 2 data matrix, A, with n > 2.  We want the columns of A to have similar variance and there to be some correlation between the columns.  You can achieve this using the choleski decomposition of a 2x2 covariance matrix.  Then we'll take the sample covariance matrix of A, lets call this B.  If we change B(1,2) = -B(1,2) then B will have complex eigen values with high probability.

The reason for this is a covariance matrix is of the form [a,b;b,c] and the fundamental equation for the matrix is (a-lam)*(c-lam) - b^2.  In order for this to have complex eigen values we need 4*a*c -4*b^2 > (a+c)^2.  Which can be written as -4*b^2 > (a-c)^2.  This can't happen, unless we change B(1,2) = -B(1,2) then the requirement becomes 4*b^2 > (a-c)^2.  So since a and c are the variances of the columns of A, if they have similar variance (a-c)^2 will be close to zero.  and if the columns of A have decent correlation then 4b^2 will be far from zero and positive.  Therefore you get complex eigen values.

This shouldn't be too hard to extend to general nxn matrices.

Comment: @Luan you should note that the eigen values of any NxN matrix are the roots of an N'th order polynomial.  As such, if N is odd there will always be at least one real root to the polynomial.  So it is not possible to generate a matrix without atleast 1 real eigen value if each element in the matrix is real and N is odd.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to extend to general nxn matrices. One issue is that if n is odd, Matlab always generates at least one real eigenvalues
e.g : n = 3
random_matrix = cov(rand(3));

```
for i = 1: length(random_matrix)
    for j = 1: length(random_matrix)
        if j > i
           random_matrix(i,j) = - random_matrix(i,j);
        end
    end    
end
```

random_matrix =

```
0.1390   -0.1389    0.0578
0.1389    0.1661    0.0257
```

-0.0578   -0.0257    0.0614

eig(random_matrix) =

0.1457 + 0.1483i

0.1457 - 0.1483i

0.0752 + 0.0000i

is there any better way to randomly generate a real stable matrix which only has imaginary part of eigenvalues ?

Answer (score 0):

Note the eigenvalues are conjugates of one another and so are the eigenvectors. Note that the resulting matrix A has all real entries.

```
>> syms a b c d e real    

>> D=diag([a+b*i,a-b*i])


D =

[ a + b*i,       0]
[       0, a - b*i]

>> V=[c, c;d+e*i, d-e*i]

V =

[       c,       c]
[ d + e*i, d - e*i]

>> A=simplify(V*D*inv(V))

A =

[          (a*e - b*d)/e,       (b*c)/e]
[ -(b*(d^2 + e^2))/(c*e), (a*e + b*d)/e]
```

Thus, suppose you want a real matrix with eigenvalues 1+i and 1-i and eigenvectors (1,1+i) and (1,1-i).

```
>> D=sym(diag([1+i,1-i]))

D =

[ 1 + i,     0]
[     0, 1 - i]

>> V=sym([1,1;1+i,1-i])

V =

[     1,     1]
[ 1 + i, 1 - i]

>> A=simplify(V*D*inv(V))

A =

[  0, 1]
[ -2, 2]
```

And we can check our answer.

```
>> [v,d]=eig(A)

v =

[ 1/2 + i/2, 1/2 - i/2]
[         1,         1]


d =

[ 1 - i,     0]
[     0, 1 + i]
```

At first, we think it didn't return the same eigenvectors that we entered. However, any multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector, and look what happens when we multiply matrix v by 1+i.

```
>> (1+i)*v

ans =

[     i,     1]
[ 1 + i, 1 + i]
```

Those are the eigenvectors we entered.

If you don't have Matlab's Symbolic Toolbox, I did this in the editor.

```
%%
clear
D=diag([1+i,1-i]);
V=[1,1;1+i,1-i];
A=V*D*inv(V)
```

And this is the output.

```
A =

     0     1
    -2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

> The non-real roots of a real polynomial with real coefficients can be grouped into pairs of complex conjugates, namely with the two members of each pair having imaginary parts that differ only in sign and the same real part. If the degree is odd, then by the intermediate value theorem at least one of the roots is real. Therefore, any real matrix with odd order has at least one real eigenvalue, whereas a real matrix with even order may not have any real eigenvalues. The eigenvectors associated with these complex eigenvalues are also complex and also appear in complex conjugate airs.
> [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#:~:text=The%20non%2Dreal,complex%20conjugate%20pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#:%7E:text=The%20non%2Dreal,complex%20conjugate%20pairs).

Let's say **A** is a random real square matrix of size *n×n* we are looking for. Since all eigenvalues were asked to be complex, they will come in conjugate pairs `x±yi` and *n* must be even. For each eigenvalue pair `x±yi`, we put *2×2* matrix
[x,-y;y,x] on the diagonal of *n×n* zero matrix (**M**).
Then for any invertible random matrix **B** of size *n×n*:

**A**=**B** * **M** * inv(**B**)

The following code creates random complex eigenvalues and generate matrix **A** based on them:

```
re = rand(n/2, 1); % real part of random eigenvalues
im = rand(n/2, 1);  % imaginary part of random eigenvalues

M = zeros(n);

% Place 2x2 blocks along the diagonal
for i = 1:n/2
    x = re(i);
    y = im(i);
    M(2*i-1:2*i, 2*i-1:2*i) = [x, -y; y, x];
end

B = rand(n);
A = B*M/B;
```